# Can we detect damage screen from background in android?

Tags: android

Can we detect device damage screen from background(broadcast) in android?

Comment: What? Not clear what you are asking. Please explain.

Comment: Ask the user, "hey, is your screen damaged?" Otherwise, I know of no way for you to automatically determine what is and is not "damage".

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

The device software has no way of knowing the condition of the device hardware.